# How to find $\frac{d^{40}y}{dx^{40}}$, when $y= \sin x$?

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry, implicit-differentiation

What approach would be ideal in finding $\frac{d^{40}y}{dx^{40}}$, when $y= \sin x$?

Comment: Well, you may notice that the fourth derivative of $\sin(x)$ is $\sin(x)$ itself. Compose the identity map $10$ times and what do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that every fourth derivative of $\sin(x)$ is $\sin(x)$ itself. Therefore we can write this statement:
$$\text{If $y=\sin x$, then }\frac{d^{4n}y}{dx^{4n}}=\sin(x) \, \, \text{($n \in \mathbb N$)}$$
$40$ is a multiple of $4$, which means that:
$$\color{green}{\frac{d^{40}y}{dx^{40}}=\sin(x)}$$
It really is that simple. Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

If $y = \sin x$, then $y^{(1)} = y' = \cos x$, and $y^{(2)} = y'' = -\sin x$, $y^{(4)} = \sin x$, so:
$y^{(8)} = \sin x$, and $y^{(40)} = \sin x$, here $y^{(n)} = \dfrac{d^{n}y}{dx^n}.$